# error with inserting data into sqlite database table in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a db table :

```
create table recentMovies5  (_id integer primary key autoincrement, line1 text, line2 text, title text , Tags text , ImageLink text , XMLLink text, entryTime numeric);
```

and am inserting values like this:

```
Insert into recentMovies5 (line1, line2, title, Tags,ImageLink,XMLLink,entryTime) Values ("3 min ", "Japan", "Ahsan", "38", "www.ahsan.com/aha.jpg", "www.ahsan.com/aha.xml",1317172213);
```

java code for inserting:

```
            String select="Insert into recentMovies5 (line1, line2, title, Tags,ImageLink,XMLLink,entryTime) Values (\"3 min \", \"Japan\", \"Ahsan\", \"38\", \"www.ahsan.com/aha.jpg\", \"www.ahsan.com/aha.xml\",1317172213)";
            SQLiteDatabase db = savedInfoDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c=db.rawQuery(select, null);
            startManagingCursor(c);
```

before I added the column `entryTime numeric`, everything was working fine. Now, no data is being inserted and I get no error message! Any help ?

edit 1:  changing entryTime from `numeric` to `integer` doesnt seem to help :(

edit 2: using this code to open the database:

```
public SavedMoviesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new RecentMovieDatabaseHelper(context);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

edit 3:  checked with both isOpen and isReadOnly =>> is open and not readonly.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert into a readable only DB.

Use [openDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29) with `OPEN_READWRITE` flag instead.

Comment: also, I used to be able to insert only some times back when I didnt have the column `timeEntry` ...